# How to toggle and check a Material UI Checkbox in Enzyme / Jest Test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, jestjs, enzyme

I've got a simple component wrapped around a Material UI Checkbox. I've stripped it down to the bare minimum here.

```
//@flow
import React from "react";
import { Checkbox } from "@material-ui/core";

function MyCheckboxComponent() {
  const [checkedState, setCheckedState] = React.useState(true);

  const handleChange = event => {
    setCheckedState(event.target.checked);
  };

  return <Checkbox checked={checkedState} onChange={handleChange} />;
}

export default MyCheckboxComponent;
```

I simply want to test this component and toggle the Checkbox value and check it. I cannot get my simple test passing. I'm at a loss as to why.

```
import React from "react";

import Enzyme, { mount } from "enzyme";
import { Checkbox } from "@material-ui/core";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";

import MyCheckboxComponent from "./MyCheckboxComponent";
Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

/** Interaction tests testing user interaction with PilzButton */
test("Toggle Checkbox test", () => {
  const wrapper = mount(<MyCheckboxComponent />);

  const checkBox = wrapper.find(Checkbox);
  expect(checkBox).toHaveLength(1);

  checkBox.simulate('change', { target: { checked: true } });

  expect(checkBox.props().checked).toBe(true);
});
```

Should 
`checkBox.simulate('change', { target: { checked: true } });` 
work and toggle the value of the `Checkbox` ??

What I have so far is here on CodeSandbox ...

[image: Edit toggle-material-ui-checkbox-jest]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Newest versions of enzyme cache the results returned from `find` and other methods.

You need to re-find and also use `.update()` to force the refresh of the state to re-render.

```js
  const checkBox = wrapper.find(Checkbox);
  expect(checkBox).toHaveLength(1);

  checkBox.simulate('change', { target: { checked: true } });

  wrapper.update();

  expect(wrapper.find(Checkbox).props().checked).toBe(true);
```

Also, this may just be because you wanted to produce a minimal reproducible question but your test is poor at the moment because your default value is true and you are passing true in dynamically.

You should do this instead:

```js
  const checkBox = wrapper.find(Checkbox);
  expect(checkBox).toHaveLength(1);
  expect(checkBox.props().checked).toBe(true);

  checkBox.simulate('change', { target: { checked: false } });

  wrapper.update();

  expect(wrapper.find(Checkbox).props().checked).toBe(false);
```

This test is actually proving that the `onChange` works properly now.

Answer (score 1):

```html
const checkBox = wrapper.find(Checkbox);
  expect(checkBox).toHaveLength(1);
  expect(checkBox.props().checked).toBe(false);

 checkBox.prop("onChange")({ currentTarget: { checked: true } });

  wrapper.update();

  expect(wrapper.find(Checkbox).props().checked).toBe(true);
```

Just a minor update to the answer above. The checkbox state doesn't change with "simulate" and instead works with "prop" for me.